# How to join two data frames in Apache Spark and merge keys into one column?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two following Spark data frames:

```
sale_df:

|user_id|total_sale|
+-------+----------+
|      a|      1100|
|      b|      2100|
|      c|      3300|
|      d|      4400
```

and target_df:

```
 user_id|personalized_target|
+-------+-------------------+
|      b|               1000|
|      c|               2000|
|      d|               3000|
|      e|               4000|
+-------+-------------------+
```

How can I join them in a way that output is:

```
user_id   total_sale   personalized_target
 a           1100            NA
 b           2100            1000
 c           3300            2000
 d           4400            4000
 e           NA              4000
```

I have tried all most all the join types but it seems that single join can not make the desired output.

Any PySpark or SQL and HiveContext can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the equi-join synthax in Scala

```
  val output = sales_df.join(target_df,Seq("user_id"),joinType="outer")
```

You should check if it works in python:

```
   output = sales_df.join(target_df,['user_id'],"outer")
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to perform an outer equi-join :

```py
data1 = [['a', 1100], ['b', 2100], ['c', 3300], ['d', 4400]]
sales = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data1,['user_id','total_sale'])
data2 = [['b', 1000],['c',2000],['d',3000],['e',4000]]
target = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data2,['user_id','personalized_target'])

sales.join(target, 'user_id', "outer").show()
# +-------+----------+-------------------+
# |user_id|total_sale|personalized_target|
# +-------+----------+-------------------+
# |      e|      null|               4000|
# |      d|      4400|               3000|
# |      c|      3300|               2000|
# |      b|      2100|               1000|
# |      a|      1100|               null|
# +-------+----------+-------------------+
```